# css "position:fixed; overflow:auto;" bad bottom padding

Tags: css, overflow, fixed

Page Fixed right-hand side and place under the headline.
[jsfiddle exapmle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0a4nmyk/) looks the way I want, but the scroll bar is beyond the edge of the screen. How to fix this situation?

```
  position:fixed;
  top:120px;
  bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:120px;
  overflow:auto;
  height: 100%
```

[jsfiddle exapmle of use](http://jsfiddle.net/L0a4nmyk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting `height:100%` on `.main-body-grid > .grid-left, .main-body-grid > .grid-right` and `.main-body-grid > .grid-left` worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much. I lost 2 hours on the setting page of the skeleton and could not understood what was going on.